# UL com CheckBox Problemas AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

Estou tentando criar uma árvore de CheckBox porem estou tendo problemas com minha diretiva ao passar o model.

> Segue código:

```
<ul class="main-level"><li>
    <mdi-input-checkbox mdi-reverse="true"
        mdi-model="checked"
        mdi-label="Elemento A">
    </mdi-input-checkbox>
<ul class="sub-level sub-level-0"><li>
    <mdi-input-checkbox mdi-reverse="true"
        mdi-model="checked"
        mdi-label="Elemento A1">
    </mdi-input-checkbox>
<ul class="sub-level sub-level-1"><li>
    <mdi-input-checkbox mdi-reverse="true"
        mdi-model="checked"
        mdi-label="Elemento A1a">
    </mdi-input-checkbox>
<ul class="sub-level sub-level-1"><li>
    <mdi-input-checkbox mdi-reverse="true"
        mdi-model="checked"
        mdi-label="Elemento A1a1">
    </mdi-input-checkbox>
</li><li>
    <mdi-input-checkbox mdi-reverse="true"
        mdi-model="checked"
        mdi-label="Elemento A1a2">
    </mdi-input-checkbox>
</li></ul></li><li>
    <mdi-input-checkbox mdi-reverse="true"
        mdi-model="checked"
        mdi-label="Elemento A1b">
    </mdi-input-checkbox>
</li></ul></li><li>
    <mdi-input-checkbox mdi-reverse="true"
        mdi-model="checked"
        mdi-label="Elemento A2">
    </mdi-input-checkbox>
<ul class="sub-level sub-level-2"><li>
    <mdi-input-checkbox mdi-reverse="true"
        mdi-model="checked"
        mdi-label="Elemento A2a">
    </mdi-input-checkbox>
</li><li>
    <mdi-input-checkbox mdi-reverse="true"
        mdi-model="checked"
        mdi-label="Elemento A2b">
    </mdi-input-checkbox>
</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>
```

se eu clicar em um está marcando todos.

Answer (score 0):

Então, este HTML é gerado automaticamente pelo meu controller, criei uma diretiva chamada Tree, ela nada mais é do que uma árvore de CheckBox certo? tive um impasse ao passar uma propriedade no ng-model para cada checkbox.

Minha diretiva tem uma função recursiva que percorre um array e retorna o HTML concatenando as Tags **UL** e **LI**, porém quando eu passava o ng-model="elemento.checked", acabou que todos os check-box tinham o mesmo nome na propriedade, ao marcar um marcava todos.

Resolvi concatenando o id de cada objeto do meu array, ficando assim:

```
<ul class="main-level">
    <li>
        <mdi-input-checkbox mdi-reverse="true"
                            mdi-model="tree[1].checked"
                            mdi-label="Elemento A">
        </mdi-input-checkbox>
        <ul class="sub-level sub-level-0">
            <li>
                <mdi-input-checkbox mdi-reverse="true"
                                    mdi-model="tree[2].checked"
                                    mdi-label="Elemento A1">
                </mdi-input-checkbox>
                <ul class="sub-level sub-level-1">
                    <li>
                        <mdi-input-checkbox mdi-reverse="true"
                                            mdi-model="tree[3].checked"
                                            mdi-label="Elemento A1a">
                        </mdi-input-checkbox>
                        <ul class="sub-level sub-level-1">
                            <li>
                                <mdi-input-checkbox mdi-reverse="true"
                                                    mdi-model="tree[4].checked"
                                                    mdi-label="Elemento A1a1">
                                </mdi-input-checkbox>   
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <mdi-input-checkbox mdi-reverse="true"
                                                    mdi-model="tree[5].checked"
                                                    mdi-label="Elemento A1a2">
                                </mdi-input-checkbox>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <mdi-input-checkbox mdi-reverse="true"
                                            mdi-model="tree[6].checked"
                                            mdi-label="Elemento A1b">
                        </mdi-input-checkbox>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <mdi-input-checkbox mdi-reverse="true"
                                    mdi-model="tree[7].checked"
                                    mdi-label="Elemento A2">
                </mdi-input-checkbox>
                <ul class="sub-level sub-level-2">
                    <li>
                        <mdi-input-checkbox mdi-reverse="true"
                                            mdi-model="tree[8].checked"
                                            mdi-label="Elemento A2a">
                        </mdi-input-checkbox>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <mdi-input-checkbox mdi-reverse="true"
                                            mdi-model="tree[9].checked"
                                            mdi-label="Elemento A2b">
                        </mdi-input-checkbox>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Para deixar ainda mais claro, na minha função recursiva, eu passo o valor assim:

```
ng-model="tree[${id}].checked"
```